# Seam Painting Problem

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I recently unwrapped a model and began painting over a seam but for some reason it still leaves this odd mark (highlighted in the red box). My Bleed is set to 8 pixels but it still gives me this odd look.

[image]

Comment: Where is the seam in that red rectangle? Is the the diagonal line crossing the black one? Or in the middle of the diagonal line? How does the uv map look like? Why do you need the seam in the middle of the flat surface? In general if those jaggies happen because of the low resolution then this seam isn't going to be easily fixable.

Comment: I probably should have visualized it better but it's near the center; you can kind of see the strokes cutting abruptly. I drew that extra squiggle right between them and, as you can see, it goes through but doesn't colour in the gap in that thicker line.

Comment: Most likely that's because black lines can't overpaint grey base texture color, Bleed doesn't always solve that. You can paint on texture in UV editor, or scale UV island after painting, or maybe painting from different points in viewport. All the ways have their disadvantages.

Comment: Ah okay. I'll have to do paint it manually on the texture via UV editor then.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the UV islands are not touching. If the bleed is 8 then the island distance needs to be 16.